# R - Merging csv files recursively for large datasets while appending file structure

Tags: r, dplyr

(I'm open to other suggestions or workflows. I'm thinking about possibly making some sort of function that converts each file individually and uploads it to the database table directly before processing the next one.  It would just need to be able to check the table first to see if the records already exist for when I use it again in the future. -or i could just drop the table each time.)

I'm working with relatively large data sets, that until now have been process-able through my code. Once I read in all of my files, I gather them from wide to long, and then merge two tables and create a couple of outputs.  The merged output prior to my latest data increase was ~80 million rows.

My newest data set results in two tables, 700 columns wide, and 3 million rows long. As I read each file in, I append two columns of data to the front end to identify the file location in my folder structure.

The trouble comes when I try to use gather to translate each table from wide to long.  I get an error that basically says the table is too big and 192GB on memory isn't going to cut it.

```
Error in melt_dataframe(data, id_idx - 1L, gather_idx - 1L, as.character(key_var),  : 
  negative length vectors are not allowed
```

There is however a LOT of dead space in each table filled with NA values. The problem is that I can't collapse the table down because of the file path columns.

CSV format:

```
sequence  place  sample1  sample2 sample3
abcdhjj     a       500    99       1000
hffdjf      b       400    1000     66
```

and so on with up to 200k rows per csv, and usually less than 60 sample columns. The combined DF's are built from ~40 files, and ~700 samples.

When I read in the files using

```
filelist=list.files(path="/sample_dir/",recursive=T,pattern=".csv",full.names=T)

mylist = tibble(file = filelist) %>%
  mutate(Data = lapply(file, read_csv)) %>%
  unnest(Data)
```

I then split the filepath and discard the columns I dont need, resulting in:

```
folder1   folder2  sequence  place  sample1  sample2 sample3 sampleA  sampleB  SampleC
A1         B2       abcdhjj     a       500    99       1000    NA      NA       NA
A1         B2        hffdjf      b       400    1000     66     NA      NA       NA
A2         B1       abcdhjj     a        NA      NA       NA    500    99       1000 
A2         B1        hffdjf      b       NA      NA       NA    400    1000     66
```

etc, with each of the 36 files bringing in a new block of samples that creates NA values for every other block. (The sequence listing however is not the same for each file.)  It would likely be better to ignore the file structure and do some sort of join as each csv file is read in to minimize the amount of NA values and reduce the overall row count. But I'm stuck seeing through to what I should do.

The ultimate desired output is a long table:

```
folder1  folder2 sample sequence place value
(~100 million rows+ long)
```

From there I would merge the matching value rows from the second table and create my final output like I was doing before the memory issue cropped up.